# Should we use Generic Collection to improve safety and performance?

Tags: c#-3.0

Should we use Generic Collection to improve safety and performance?

Comment: I wonder somewhat about the legitimacy of this account, as he has asked two very simple karma gathering type questions, and not voted or answered on anything.

Comment: I just work as a software developer, and i have no experiences so i need to ask someone to help me.

Answer (score 5):

Of course. Why wouldn't you? More important than the performance, IMO, is the fact that generic APIs are more expressive. That goes for generic APIs in general, not just collections.

EDIT: Just to clarify these a bit:

- Performance characteristics are slightly different between the generic and nongeneric collections for reasons of "they're different implementation" as well as the whole generic/nongeneric side. Obviously the generic version avoids boxing/unboxing and (in most use cases) an execution time cast when fetching. In practice this is only likely to be significant for value types, where the boxing comes into play. For large collections, it's the difference in memory usage which is likely to be more significant than the execution *speed* difference.
- I'm slightly less bothered by the actual type-safety aspect. It's certainly a good thing, but I can't remember ever actually seeing a bug when using the nongeneric collections due to putting the wrong type in (or fetching it as the wrong type). It's certainly a benefit though.
- I view the expressiveness as *very* important. I can glance at the declaration of a method and know what to expect from the return value - I don't need to read the documentation quite as closely, or give variables quite as unwieldy names or docs. In addition you get all the benefits of Intellisense etc. One of the questions to ask about a language is "what can I express in it?" and generics allows much richer concepts to be expressed than before.

Comment: Not to mention that some of the Generic collections are just plain better implemented than the non generic ones, take HashTable versus Dictionary<K,V> for example.

Comment: @Jonathan: I can't remember offhand what the differences between HashTable and Dictionary are. Care to elaborate?

Comment: If I recall right, Hashtable has a rather ugly spinlock in it for synchronization.

Comment: Ick. I don't like synchronization being in the collections to start with, to be honest... it's very rarely the right place for it :(

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't generics simply a compile time construct (I believe they are in Java - can't vouch for c#) and they compile to the same code as the non-generic version would.
The docs say that List<int> compiles to the same as List<double>.

Comment: @belugabob: No, .NET generics aren't anything like Java generics. The type information is preserved and used by the JIT. So a List<byte> with a million elements will just take up a million bytes (plus overhead for spare capacity, size etc - but no boxing).

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

A conventional collection, such as the ArrayList, implicitly stores objects.

This means, that doing this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(5);
list.Add("FooBar");
```

Is legitimate code. This introduces a handful of issues.

- Normally, you don't want to store different types in the same collection, and having compile time checking for this is nice.
- When you store a value type (such as the integer 5 above), it must be boxed into a reference type before it can be stored in the collection.
- When reading a value, you must cast it back from Object to the desired type.

However, you eliminate all of these issues by using a generic collection:

```
List<int> list = new List();
list.Add(5);
// Compile Time Error.
list.Add("FooBar")
```

You also gain intellisense support when working directly with indices of the collection, instead of just generic "object" intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

Longer answer: There are really no downsides to using generic collections. Compile-time type checking eliminates the posibility of runtime errors from casting. Performance will be greater for built-in types such as integers, since boxing and unboxing are not needed (in contrast to Java generic collections, by the way)

Comment: Thats because Java's type erasure replaces generic code with conventional Object casting behind the scenes regardless.